# How do I call for variables from another method in same class, as well as call upon the method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, call

I am struggling to understand the concept of declaring and calling upon classes as well as the traffic of variables between them. 
In the code I have now I believe there are several problems, but the main one right now is that the main-method isn't able to use the returned value from another method, I do believe I got the rest right. 
The code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Uke63{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        char c='t';
        String tekst="Jabba the Hutt var en stygg fyr";

        forekommer(c, tekst);

        System.out.println(retval.forekommer);

    }

    static boolean forekommer(char c, String tekst){

        boolean retval=tekst.contains(c);
        return retval;
    }
}
```

And the error I get when trying to compile: (I do see that it doesn't find the value, but I need some help on how to make it find that particular value.)

```
makri@Marius-samlap:~/Programmering/Ukeoppgaver$ javac Uke63.java
Uke63.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(retval.forekommer);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable retval
  location: class Uke63
Uke63.java:18: error: method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types;
    boolean retval=tekst.contains(c);
                        ^
  required: CharSequence
  found: char
  reason: actual argument char cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion
2 errors
```

Comment: The errors are there to help you, read them!

Comment: Where on earth did you get the notion to use this syntax? `System.out.println(retval.forekommer);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your code to this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Uke63{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    char c='t';
        String tekst="Jabba the Hutt var en stygg fyr";

    System.out.println(forekommer(c, tekst));

    }

    static boolean forekommer(char c, String tekst){

    boolean retval=tekst.contains(c);
    return retval;
    }
}
```

Problems in Original Code:You are trying to access local variable declared in forekommer() method in main which is not possible.

Comment: The way Algorithmist solves this is correct, it can be intresting for you to check out: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your main method you do not have access to "retval".
After you call your forekommer method you need to assign the result to a local variable. 
for example:

```
boolean someVarName =forekommer(c, tekst);
System.out.println(someVarName );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, refined some of the answers here and made the code compile and run.

```
public class Uke63{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        CharSequence c=  "t";
        String tekst="Jabba the Hutt var en stygg fyr";
        System.out.println(forekommer(c, tekst));
    }

    private static boolean forekommer(CharSequence c, String tekst){
        return  tekst.contains(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSequence c = "t";
        String tekst="Jabba the Hutt var en stygg fyr";
        boolean x = forekommer(c, tekst);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    static boolean forekommer(CharSequence c, String tekst){
        CharSequence x = c;
        boolean retval = tekst.contains(x);
        return retval;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.